# Как удалить все символы из stdin после получения доступа к серверу?

Tags: c++, winapi, синхронизация

Существует сервер, в котором запускается n-ое количество процессов. Синхронизация происходит с помощью мьютекса. Клиенты обрабатываются последовательно по одному.

Сервер запускает какое-то количество процессов (.exe). На первом шаге сервер принимает сообщения от клиента, который "схавал" мьютекс, а другие клиенты ожидают освобождения мьютекса. Клиент, который ждет мьютекс не может отправлять сообщения серверу.

Представим сценарий:

Я пытаюсь ввести какие-то данные в клиента, который в данный момент не обрабатывается сервером. Эти данные естественно никак не отправляются серверу и якобы не вводятся, на самом деле эти данные помещаются во входной потом, но они на этом этапе никак не визуализируются в консоле.

С какой проблемой я столкнулся:

После того, как клиент, который не имел доступа к серверу, наконец, его получает он автоматически отправляет все символы, введенные до этого серверу, по одному.

Ниже код клиента, демонстрирующий текущий (некорректный функционал):

```
HANDLE hMutex = CreateMutex(0, FALSE, L"DemoMutex");
    char ch  = ' ';
    WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE);
    while (ch != 'E') {
        cin >> ch;

    }
    ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
    CloseHandle(hMutex);
```

Я пытался придумать костыль, по типу, считать все из cin с помощью getline, но данный метод считывает все данные до переноса строки, то есть, если я не ввожу `'\n'` клиент все равно отправляет все символы по одному серверу.

В итоге я хочу избавиться от символов, которые, как бы, были введены заранее, до того как клиент получил доступ к серверу.

Comment: *"писать одновременно в два и более exe"*, *"те символы, которые мы пытались туда ввести"* - в приведенных участках кода ничего такого нету

Comment: cin >> ch в клиенте

Comment: это попытка чтения из стандартного ввода

Comment: ну, я ввожу что-то в консоль и считываю командой cin

Comment: @СараскинЮрий это нормальное поведение для потоков ввода, эти символы не отправляются же на сервер.

Comment: @СараскинЮрий можете попробовать использовать getch()

Comment: @j6wj1997 c getch() тоже самое, это упрощенная версия моей программы. В  основной я передаю то, что ввел на сервер. То есть getch тоже сохраняет то, что я вводил в закрытую консоль. Как сделать так, чтобы эти символы не сохранялись?

Comment: Сделайте в клиенте 2 потока. Один читает stdin, второй общается с сервером. Пока 2-й не выставит признак соединения с сервером 1-й просто отбрасывает все прочитанные символы. После соединения он начинает передавать прочитанные символы потоку, общающемуся с сервером.